# Use Multiple Columns in Regex in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I want to use regex_replace to remove phrases that exist in one (or both) of two columns. So from the product name I want to remove the colour and brand that exist in the colour or brand columns. I have regex like this, but I wonder if you can do it without nesting?

```
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(lower(product_name), 
    lower(Manufacturer_Brand_Name), ''),lower(Colour), '')
```

so instead of the above have something like

```
regexp_replace(lower(product_name), 
    (lower(Manufacturer_Brand_Name)|lower(Colour)), '')
```

But obviously you have to put it in quotation marks to read as regex, so then I'm not actually inputting the column names

```
regexp_replace(lower(product_name), 
    '(lower(Manufacturer_Brand_Name)|lower(Colour))', '')
```

The expected result is Dell Laptop Blue to just Laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(product_name, CONCAT(r'(?i)', Manufacturer_Brand_Name, '|', Colour), '')
```

For example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Dell Laptop Blue' product_name, 'Dell' Manufacturer_Brand_Name, 'blue' Colour
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(product_name, CONCAT(r'(?i)', Manufacturer_Brand_Name, '|', Colour), '')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   Laptop
```